# Golang get mux value

Tags: go

I'm new to go. I'm using mux and trying to parse out a url parameter. I have the following code where r is a `*http.Request`

```
vars := mux.Vars(r)
user := vars["user"]
fmt.Print(user)
```

mux grabs the whole url parameter string like the following print out.

> "user=username"

I'm wondering if it's possible to simply grab the value (`username`), or if I need to do regex to get the username.

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mux's Vars attribute is more for parsing path variables such as `user/{id}` and being able to extract out that information. For actual URL query parameters, you're better off using the built-in request Query() object.

```
user := r.URL.Query().Get("user")
```